# Draw a line to the right of the text (HTML/CSS) (Compatible IE6)

Tags: html, css

How can I draw a line to the right of the text, for exemple : "Title _______"
The line must complete all the div. Without image and IE6 compatible.

I currently do like this :

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <h1 class="title">My Title</h1>
</div>

.title {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: rgb(102,102,204);
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom:2px solid #000;
    border-color: rgb(102,102,204);
}
```

But the line is in bad position.

Thanks

Comment: Apply white background for text to cover line below text (`position: relative; top: 2px;`

Comment: **IE6!** Really? IE8 is simple enough but IE6 is probably going to require additional elements. Are you happy with that?

Comment: Yeah IE6, havn't choice :), maybe i can do it with table, and draw bot border on second td

Answer (score 0):

you can use pseudo element here and given border to .title:after()

```css
.title {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: rgb(102,102,204);
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 14px;
}

.title::after {
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    border-color: rgb(102,102,204);
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
    <h1 class="title">My Title</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but isn't support by IE6 :S

Answer (score 0):

```css
#myDiv {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}


.title {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  
    color: rgb(102, 102, 204);
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 2px 7px;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
}
```

```html
you can given border to div and give white background to title.
<div id="myDiv">
    <h1 class="title">My Title<span></span></h1>
</div>
```